# extract a column from a line in a bash script

Tags: bash

Having a file with this format:

```
aa: bb.cc:dd.e Text1: text
cc: aa.bb:dd.e Text2: text
dd: cc.bb:aa.e Text3: text
```

I want to obtain the output:

```
aa: Text1: text
cc: Text2: text
dd: Text3: text
```

I tried with cut, first obtained the first column then the last column:

```
(cat file1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
(cat file1 | cut -d' ' -f3-)
```

How can I do this in one command, directly extract the second column or how to use the two commands to obtain what I need?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way for this specific case:

```
cut -d' ' -f1,3,4
```

You can also try ranges (say, if you want to drop column 3):

```
cut -d' ' -f-2,4-
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` perhaps?

```
awk '{print $1 " " $3 " " $4}' file1
```

If it's a bit more complex (and the number of columns is unknown), then you can use something a bit fancier:

```
awk '{print $1 " " substr($0, index($0,$3))}' file1
```

Like before, print out the first column, but then print the substring of the entire line (`$0`) starting at when the third column (`$3`) is found.

Comment: If I have more than 4 fields to print.. If my line is extended like this: "aa: bb.cc:dd.e Text1: a1: a2: a3: a4..." can I print with awk $1 and the rest of the line excepting $2, to obtain "aa: Text1: a1: a2: a3: a4.."? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, though the substring matching might get a bit weird.